# Piping ADComputer objects to New-PSDrive

Tags: powershell

So I'm trying to get a list of servers from AD, and then create New-PSDrive's with the $*.Name and $*.DNSHostname properties.

```
$Servers = Get-ADComputer -filter blah blah gets a list of servers


$Servers | ForEach-Object {New-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem -Credential $creds -Name $_.Name -Root \\$_.DNSHostname\D$}
```

I *think* it has something to do with the double backslash followed by the $_ in the UNC path. I have tried single and double quotes and backticks in and around the DNSHostname part but I just can't work out why it won't pass the pipeline object I want into the parameter. In ISE, the "colours" aren't right..... and the command doesn't work so...

I've tried

```
-Root \\$_.DNSHostname\D$
-Root \\"$_."DNSHostname\D$
-Root `\`\$_.DNSHostname\D$
-Root "\\$_.DNSHostname\D$"
```

etc

Probably just my understanding of quotes, single, double, backticks.....

Thank you for reading :)

Comment: "I think it": what is "it"? Are you getting an error, or is it failing silently? (I assume it isn't working: but you do not say even that!)

Comment: New-PSDrive : The Network path was not found. CouldNotMapNetworkDrive,Microsoft.Powershell.Commands.NewPSDriveCommand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to correctly interpolate the `$_.DNSHostname` and escape the `$` in `D$`.

Try:

```
-Root "\\$($_.DNSHostname)\D`$"
```

Comment: Minor correction: the `$` in `D$` doesn't require escaping. It doesn't hurt either, though.

Comment: Thank you!! That has worked. Now, can you help my understand or point me to the help that explains *why* I needed to have $($ and the backtick where it is?

Comment: @bluffalo because `DNSHostname` is a property of the pipeline variable `$_` you need to wrap it into a new variable with `$(..)` to use it in a string. You need the other backtick because `$` is what denotes a variable in powershell and in your case you need it to be a literal `$` as `D$`. As @ansgar points out it isn't strictly necessary here, but can help to demonstrate when it is/isn't necessary.